# asp.net MVC 3 DateTime linq

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, datetime

I have a table of events, I need a linq query that will return all events from a certain month and year, not day.

something like

```
var monthquery = from c in db.events
                  where c.startdate.month == DateTime(MonthValue, Year Value)
                  select c;
```

I just don't know the syntax. What do I put in instead of MonthValue to get July, for instance?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of MonthValue, you can put the integer that represents the month ...

```
var monthquery = from c in db.events
                  where c.startdate.month == IntegerThatRepresentTheMonth 
                  && C.startDate.Year == IntegerThatRepresentTheYear
                  select c;
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm only beginning this lark, your help is appreciated!

Comment: Could I pick your brain further? I have two functions to set the month and year and I'v replaced the integer values with these functions, but I'm getting this error  ...  LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 GetMonth()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.... Any idea how I use a function in a linq query?

Comment: Sorry for the later. We're very busy in my officce. Well...I think you can't use this kind of custom functions inside a Linq Query. Just call the functions before and store the result inside a var. Then, in the linq query, compare against this var. In addition, this two more lines of code will let you read and debug your app in an easy way.